# Using UML Diagrams as clickable objects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I want to create a site that will be used internally to explain how our lengthy, complex Java code works. I have been able to create some UML Class, Components, and Package Diagrams and want to be able to embed the Diagrams into my site. Obviously, I can embed it as a .png or some other style of image, but what I would like to do, for example, is make it possible for someone to click on a package and have that go into an exploded view of the package's contents.

To try and better clarify my question, I'll try to give a more detailed illustration of what I mean. Suppose I have this UML Diagram of `Components` and I want each of these `Components` to be treated as clickable objects, similar to any site that have images that contain `href` link properties. That would would then open into a new page that contains another UML Diagram showing only the codes, libraries, etc for that particular `Component`.

[image: Example of UML Component Diagram]

Is it possible to embed my UML Diagrams that, for a lack of better term, contain an object with a `href` property for each `Component`? From all I've read, this is not a common use for the UMLs and I have found no documentation that supports this ability; which leads me to believe it is not possible. However, maybe I've missed something or someone knows a way to do this? Finding a way to implement this will become even more helpful when I get into showing the UML Class Diagrams and how they all interact within the program.

As a side note, this is a UML I created, and I'm using a trial version of Edraw Max, hence the "Unlicensed Version" notation. I have also used the SimpleUML plugin for IntelliJ Idea that created a UML Class Diagram, but I have not been able to export that diagram to a usable format.

Comment: FWIW: With Enterprise Architect you can export the model as HTML where the elements are clickable.

Comment: also you can use **Ratinal Rose** for their element can be clickable.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm looking at the right thing; is that supposed to be **Rational Rose**? @maryamsoltani

Comment: @brehma , yes I'm sure about.

Comment: Hello @brehma, I'm looking for the exact same behaviour. Did you find any suitable UML tool ?

Comment: @Fundhor I wound up using the IBM Rational Software Architect. Unfortunately, it's not a free product, however, it does have versatile and flexible capability. It does create web pages with the interactive design. I do recommend it; we've purchased 5 use licenses for an automated deploy through jenkins trigger to a docker that will grab the new build, update the uml, store the old, and launch the updated models.